# JPA Criteria query group by uses only the id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, group-by, criteriaquery

This is a sample entity:

```
public class Account{

   @Id
   Long id
   Double remaining;
   @ManyToOne
   AccountType type
}

public class AccountType{
   @Id
   Long id;
   String name;
}
```

Now i create a criteria query with Join as follwing :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createquery();
Root<Account> accountRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Account.class);
Join<Account, AccountType> typeJoin = accountRoot.join(Account_.type);

criteriaQuery.multiSelect(
    typeJoin,
    criteriaBuilder.sum(accountRoot.get(Account_.remaining))
);

criteriaQuery.groupBy(typeJoin);
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.getResultList();
```

The above code generate Sql command like following:

```
select accType.id, accType.name, sum(acc.remaining)
from account acc join accType on acc.accounttype_id = accType.id
group by accType.id
```

Above code work in PosgreSQL but can't run in Oracle, because in it select accType.name that doesn't appear in the group by clause.

**update** :
I think my question isn't clear for you. My question isn't about PostgreSQL or Oracle behavior in `group by`. My question is this :
I use `typeJoin` in `group by` clause(this means I expect hibernate use all field of AccountType in `group by`), but why hibernate just use identity field on `group by`? if I will use just identity field in `group by` then I can use the following statement :

```
criteriaQuery.groupBy(typeJoin.get(AccountType_.id)) ;
```

Answer (score 16):

JPA/Hibernate doesn't automatically include all entity properties in a group by clause, so you have to manually specify them:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root<Account> accountRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Account.class);
Join<Account, AccountType> typeJoin = accountRoot.join(Account_.type);

criteriaQuery.multiSelect(
    typeJoin.get("id"),
    typeJoin.get("name"),
    criteriaBuilder.sum(accountRoot.get(Account_.remaining))
);

criteriaQuery.groupBy(typeJoin.get("id"), typeJoin.get("name"));
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.getResultList();
```

Comment: this is not good idea. In this solution any time AccountType changed i most change all of my queries. of course i can handle it by reflection but i think must be there  a better solution for it. are you sure hibernate cann't include all entitiy properties?

Comment: You can simply specify the accountType.id and use a 2nd level cache to load it afterwards.

Comment: You could of course also use the JPA Metamodel to retrieve all attributes of the entity type and put them into the group by which would be generic.

Comment: @VladMihalcea is that stil the case ? I'm facing this problem, I wonder if there is a workaround now ?

Comment: Most likely this is still the case since this is not really an issue. If anyone wants to add an improvement via a `QueryHint`, then the query could possible to the GROUP BY all columns.

Comment: The solution works greate, but now `createQuery()` method is parametrized. If someone facing with: "Raw use of parameterized class 'CriteriaQuery'" warning the solution is to use POJO to wrap the query result: `CriteriaQuery<AccountAggregationDTO> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(AccountAggregationDTO.class);`. The AccountAggregationDTO class must include constructor with three parameters:  Long, String, Double, to avoid `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class`.

Answer (score 6):

If using GROUP BY, Oracle requires every column in select list to be in the GROUP BY.
PostgreSQL is the same, except when grouping by the primary key, then it allows you to select any column.

From [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035)

> In a query containing a GROUP BY clause, the elements of the select
>   list can be aggregate functions, GROUP BY expressions, constants, or
>   expressions involving one of these.

From [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it
>   is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped
>   columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column
>   is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would
>   otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped
>   column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a
>   subset thereof) **are the primary key of the table containing the
>   ungrouped column.**